# I changed my hostname, rebooted and lost internet connection

Tags: linux, rhel, hostname, domain

I set a new hostname on my machine using:

```
sudo hostname NEWHOSTNAME
```

Then I restarted, and tried accessing the internet and nothing happened. I checked the hostname and it was set to `localhost.localdomain`.

How can I reset my configurations so that I am again connected to the web?

I'm running Red Hat Enterprise 6.0 (Santiago)

Comment: what exactly did you do to change the hostname?

Comment: I did: sudo hostname NEWHOSTNAME

Comment: This changes the hostname until you reboot. Maybe you did something else ?

Comment: Agreed with @BenD: the original hostname would be restored after the reboot.

Comment: Thanks guys, I wasn't sure if it was a persistent change or not. Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hostname should have nothing to do with being able to connect to the internet. That is unless the DHCP server on your network assigns IP addresses based on hostname (which if it does, it's a big mistake).

If the internet loss you mention is on a home network, consider restarting your local router. If it's a public or work network, unplug the cable/disable wireless, wait a few seconds and try plugging/enabling again.

If you still have problems, ask your local administrator.
If you are your local administrator, follow the steps [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-network-interface-configuration/) or ask for [support](http://www.redhat.com/support/).

Answer (score 0):

In centos 6, clean. I change the `/etc/hosts` file to add a fqdn, like:

```
192.168.1.118 mail.sla.com mail
```

before I change the file `/etc/systemconfig/network` an add a name different a localhost.localdomain, like:

```
HOSTNAME: mail
```

next, I execute `yum install bind`, and result is "couln't find centos.mirror...."

`ping` to dns of isp... nothing

What would be the explanation for that?

Answer (score 0):

As someone already mentioned, check the file /etc/sysconfig/network

NETWORKING_IPV6=no

HOSTNAME=

NETWORKING=yes

GATEWAY=

the HOSTNAME entry on this file will make the hostname of the server permanent after restart.

Restart nettwork

$ service network restart

Ping the entry GATEWAY IP address to check connectivity. If this is a home network, it would be your router.